# I have a bounded sequence $(x_n)$ with all positive terms and I have to show that $\lim(n^2/x_n) = \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am given a bounded sequence $(x_n)$ and have to show that $\lim{(n^2/x_n)} = \infty$. I am struggling to conect the bounded condition of $(x_n)$ to showing that a limit of another sequence diverges. I have considered different cases of $\alpha$, where $\alpha \leq 0$ and $\alpha>0$. But, for either cases I still struggle with getting to point where $(n^2/x_n)$ is introduced.

Comment: What is $\alpha $ ?

Comment: $|x_n|<M\implies |\frac{n^2}{x_n}|>\frac{n^2}M$ there is not much to do.

Comment: Sorry, the definition is that we say $(x_n)$ tends to $\infty$ if for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a natural number $K(\alpha)$ such that if $n \geq K(\alpha)$, then $x_n > \alpha$.

Comment: zwim, thank you, but where do I go from there to show that $n^2/x_n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: notice $M>0$...

Comment: Note that zwim's method for any positive monotonic increasing unbounded sequence instead of $n^2$.

Answer (score 0):

From the fact tht $(x_n)$ is bounded we know that there exists $M$, such that $|x_n|<M$. Now we can see that $$\left|\frac{n^2}{x_n}\right|=\frac{n^2}{|x_n|}>\frac{n^2}{M}$$
From the definition of limit of sequence, we can let $\varepsilon = \frac{n^2}{M}$ and we know that $\exists N=N(\varepsilon)$ such that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\ge N$ we have $\left|\frac{n^2}{x_n}\right|>\varepsilon$. Thus your limit diverges, i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n^2}{x_n}}=\infty$.

(I'm guessing your $\alpha$ is usually represented as $\varepsilon$ and $K(\alpha)$ as $N(\varepsilon)$, like in my answer. Also it should be that $\alpha >0$.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's use your definition of a divergent sequence.

The case where $\alpha \le 0$ is trivial, since it is given that $\{ x_n \}$ is a sequence of positive numbers; it is easy to see that $x_n > 0 \implies \frac{n^2}{x_n} > 0 \implies \alpha < \frac{n^2}{x_n}$; this holds for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ (select $K = 1$).

Since $\{ x_n \}$ is given to be bounded, we have that $0 < x_n < M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ for some $M \in \mathbb{R}$; note that $M > 0$. If $\alpha > 0$, then consider $K = \left\lfloor \alpha M \right\rfloor + 1$. You can check that $\alpha < \frac{n}{x_n} \le \frac{n^2}{x_n}$ for all $n \ge K$.

Since $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ was arbitrary, the sequence $\{ \frac{n^2}{x_n} \}$ diverges.

Comment: It seems less complicated to me to consider $\forall A>0$ let $n_0=\max(A,M)$ then $\forall n>n_0$ we have $\frac nM>1$ and therefore $\frac{n^2}{M}>n>A$ which is the definition of divergence